# kibana in the kebernets cluster doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes

I'm facing the issue as following when i append logging addon to the kubernete cluster ,the kibana doesn't work,any clue to troubleshoot it? thank in advance.

kubectl get  pod/kibana-logging-v1-mertn --namespace=kube-system

> NAME                      READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
>
> kibana-logging-v1-mertn   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   8          21m

kubectl logs  pod/kibana-logging-v1-mertn --namespace=kube-system

`ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch-logging.kube-system:9200
{"@timestamp":"2016-04-19T02:39:08.559Z","level":"error","message":"Service Unavailable","node_env":"production","error":{"message":"Service Unavailable","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Service Unavailable\n  at respond (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:235:15)\n  at checkRespForFailure (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n  at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n  at IncomingMessage.bound (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n  at _stream_readable.js:944:16\n  at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)\n"}}
{"@timestamp":"2016-04-19T02:39:08.652Z","level":"fatal","message":"Service Unavailable","node_env":"production","error":{"message":"Service Unavailable","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Service Unavailable\n  at respond (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:235:15)\n  at checkRespForFailure (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n  at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n  at IncomingMessage.bound (/kibana-4.0.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n  at _stream_readable.js:944:16\n  at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)\n"}}`

Answer (score 0):

How did you create kibana? Did you create an elasticsearch service for it to talk to?

Did you follow [the guide for setting it up during cluster creation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/logging-elasticsearch/)?